# In SAS, verify if a specified column exist in every table listed in a table

Tags: sas

I use SAS 9.4.

I have a table of table names, having two columns: libname and memname, which is the name of library and name of table, as example blow:

```
libname | memname
lib1    | table1
lib2    | table2
```

For every record, I would like to verify if a column LIKE '%CLI%' with type string and contains only digits. Every table contains at most one column satisfying these conditions.

Finally, I would like to have add the name of the found column to the table of table name as a new column:

```
libname | memname | colname
lib1    | table1  | client
lib2    | table2  | cli_num
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please show what code you have tried.  I would probably write a macro that would analyze one table, then use the metadata table to generate macro calls.

Answer (score 2):

Checking existence and type can be done without actually opening the data sets. But we need to open them to check that the values are all digits. Here is a looping construct you could use, including relevant tests and example data.

```
/*  CLI exists, contains only digits*/
data ex1;
    input other $ CLI $;
    datalines;
x 1234
x 5787
;

/*  CLI exists, doesn't contains only digits*/
data ex2;
    input other $ CLI $;
    datalines;
x 123a
x 5787
;


/*  CLI exists, isn't character*/
data ex3;
    input other $ CLI;
    datalines;
x 1234
x 5787
;

/*  CLI doesn't exist*/
data ex4;
    input other $ other2;
    datalines;
x 1234
x 5787
;

/*  Makes a table of the datasets*/
data tableoftables;
    input libname $ memname $;
datalines;
work ex1
work ex2
work ex3
work ex4
;

%macro do_stuff(indata=);
/*  A data set to collect test results and present them to user.*/
data out;
    set &indata;
    length exists $3 type $9. alldigits $3.;
run;
/*  Put libname and data set names into macro variables*/
data _null_;
    set &indata;
    call symput(cat('libname', _n_), libname);
    call symput(cat('memname', _n_), memname);
run;

/*  Find the number of datasets to loop through*/
proc sql noprint;   
    select count(*)
    into :rows
    from &indata;

/*  Loop over data sets*/
%do i=1 %to &rows;
    /*If CLI was in a specific place, you could use varnum, like here: https://communities.sas.com/message/154973. To use like, it's easier to go through proc contents*/
    /*  Create data ser with variables*/
    proc contents noprint data=&&libname&i...&&memname&i  out=row&i;
    run;

    /*  Test 1: Is variable in file*/
    /*  Infile is initiated as 0, but turns to 1 if there is at least one variable like '%CLI%'. Type and name are collected*/
    %let infile=0;
    data test&i;
        set row&i;
        where name like '%CLI%';
        call symput('infile', 1);
        call symput('type', type);
        call symput('name', name);
    run;

    /*  Test 2: Is variable character*/
    %let typetext=-;
    %if &infile=1 %then %do;
        %if &type=2 %then %let typetext=Character;
        %else %if &type=1 %then %let typetext=Numeric;
    %end;

    /*  Test 3: Does variable only contain digits*/
    %let alldigits=-;
    data test3&i;
        set &&libname&i...&&memname&i end=eof;
        retain test;
        if _n_=1 then test=0;
        notdigit=notdigit(strip(&name));
        test+notdigit;
        if eof then do;
            if test=0 then call symput('alldigits', "YES");
            else call symput('alldigits', "NO");
        end;
    run;

    data out;
        set out;
        if _n_=&i then do;
            if &infile=1 then exists="YES";
            else exists="NO";
            type="&typetext";
            alldigits="&alldigits";
        end;
    run;

%end;

proc print data=out;
run;


%mend;
%do_stuff(indata=tableoftables)
```